# Status not triggering job

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-jira-trigger

This plugin has been working great for about a year until today. This is the workflow we have in JIRA:

[image: JIRA Workflow]
At either "QA on dev" and "QA on stage", we trigger a build in our pipeline. Since we set this up a year ago, both statuses would trigger the build but today, only "QA on dev" triggers the build successfully. When we reach "QA on stage", the Jenkins log returns us an error:

https://gist.github.com/patrickng/8c77e8360290c7c0073b1f7adfbae18e

Is it possible that Atlassian changed their API all of a sudden? How can we fix this? Our workflow is now disrupted and I can't seem to think of a workaround.

Comment: JIRA issue has been raised here: [JENKINS-49178](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49178)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Atlassian made a few changes to the payload that's being posted to the webhook. If you do not have a Description set in the specific  workflow in JIRA, it will not be included in the POST request. After adding a description to the QA on stage status, the pipeline works again.

There is a separate issue with this plugin now in that comments don't trigger builds, but it looks like the plugin will need an update because JIRA now provides new events and payload for comments created/updated/edited actions.